# Authorization Code Grant: is it safe to send the tokens to the client?

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, openid-connect

Let's say I have a SPA with a back-end on the same domain. If I had to connect to an external OAuth provider (let's say Google), the Authorization Code Flow (without PKCE) is the safer option. This means that:

- The SPA requests a `code` to the Authorization Server
- Then, it sends that `code` to the back-end
- The back-end exchanges the `code` (and a secret) with the AS in order to get the **tokens**
- The back-end sets a **Session Cookie** with the SPA to keep the user logged in

This flow is the most secure because the SPA **never sees a single token**. It doesn't use them. If I have to make a request to the API with the Access Token, the SPA will make a request to the back-end which in turn will use the Access Token to get the resources. And the back-end is also responsible for using the Refresh Token. So far so good.

Now, what if the back-end, upon successful exchange (once it gets the tokens), sends the tokens **back to the browser**? That way, the client can hit the API's endpoints on its own.

In theory, this should be avoided if I'm not mistaken. Giving the tokens back to the front-end kinda defeats the purpose of the Authorization Code Grant, you might as well use the Authorization Code w/ PKCE in order to get the tokens on the front-end directly, right? With the Code Grant, it's the back-end that gets authenticated, not the SPA.

But I'm thinking: that's what **Firebase** does, isn't it? As far as I know, Firebase uses the Authorization Code (without PKCE), redirects to the Firebase App's back-end (*__auth/handler*) and then **it still gives the tokens to the front-end** (id token, access token, refresh token).

Am I missing something? Or is it ok to give the tokens to the front-end at the end of the Authorization Code Grant?

PS. Obviously, in the Firebase case, the back-end will not actually use those tokens, it relies on the browser ones that are sent in each request I imagine. In the case I mentioned though, the back-end stores those tokens so in theory I'll have 2 sets of tokens: the ones that the back-end received with the code exchange, and the ones that get sent to the browser (initially they're the same, but they're different after the first refresh). Should the back-end discard the tokens completely and rely on the browser ones? I assume it should, because if Refresh Token Rotation is enabled, the back-end would have an invalidated Refresh Token after the first refresh by the browser. This situation is driving me nuts. My opinion is that the tokens should remain on the back-end, but I'm trying to figure out how can the Firebase approach be safe.

Answer (score 2):

I clarified my original answer here, since my understanding has moved on since then.

**2023 UPDATE**

If using access tokens in the browser, it is recommended to keep the tokens short lived, confidential and to store them only in memory. But the only way to avoid usability issues is likely to be storing refresh tokens in local storage.

The [OAuth for Browser Based Apps](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps) doc provides latest best practices. This leads many people to use a backend for frontend to issue the latest `samesite=strict` cookies for the app. This is also generally perceived to be more secure by stakeholders.

For some background on threats that concern people, see my [Browser Threat Model](https://authguidance.com/browser-threat-model) blog post. I wrote this when producing my blog's final SPA, which uses a BFF approach.

Comment: It's true what you say about Access Tokens, but the thing that bothers me with the "Firebase approach" is that the browser also gets the Refresh Token and it stores it in indexedDB. So: it's not short lived, it's not stored securely, not confidential anymore. But then, it's kinda obvious why this approach is needed: if the browser only got an Access Token, what could it do once it expires? It'd have to re-ask for permission to the user, a really really bad UX. If the Authorization Server is on the same domain you can perform Silent Renew, ok, but what if it's not the case? Seems risky to me!

Comment: Regarding the downsides you mention: 1) I agree, the double hop is less efficient (but more secure), 2) you could use a non-centralized Redis server instead of Sticky Sessions, in case your app grows and you need a load balancer, 3) I'm not a mobile expert, but can't you use Cookies on mobile as well with the same mechanism? If not, I think if your company or project is big enough to have a mobile counterpart, implementing 2 strategies shouldn't be a problem :) So I agree these are downsides but solvable ones!

Comment: I agree with you on refresh tokens - I always avoid storing them in the browser, or using local storage of tokens in the browser. The Authorization Server will issue its own session cookie that can be used for access token renewal if needed - or you can do this within the app as you are doing ...